# How get my ticker variable to change my totalMoves when the user is able to move a piece?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a 15 piece slider puzzle and came across a problem. I want my start function to track the amount of moves the user takes until the user wins, but I haven't been able to understand why it doesn't work. It says my totalMoves variable is undefined so how do I define it? I tried using ticker.innerHTML when totalMoves changed but had no luck.

```js
var gamePiece;
var notify;
var timer;
var spaceY;
var spaceX;
var ticker;

function initialize() {
    var puzzleArea = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
    gamePiece = puzzleArea.getElementsByTagName("div"); //retrieve element within puzzlearea

    for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) //applies features to each puzzle piece 

    {

        gamePiece[i].className = 'puzzlepiece'; //setting up the puzzle piece code

        gamePiece[i].style.left = (i % 4 * 100) + 'px'; //calculates the position for puzzle pieces from the left of the screen

        gamePiece[i].style.top = (parseInt(i / 4) * 100) + 'px'; //calculates the position for puzzle pieces from the top of the screen






        gamePiece[i].onmouseover = function () //applies features when mouse moves over puzzle pieces

        {
            if (checkMove(parseInt(this.innerHTML))) //checks whenever a move is made

            {

                this.style.border = "3px solid red"; //changes to red when a puzzle piece is near an empty space

                this.style.color = "#006600"; //text color changes to green when a puzzle piece is near an empty space

                this.style.textDecoration = "underline"; //underlines the number of the puzzle piece piece
            
                display();

            }
        }


        gamePiece[i].onmouseout = function () //activates whenever mouse moves out of puzzle piece

        {

            this.style.border = "2px solid black"; //reverts to its original size border 

            this.style.color = "#000000"; //reverts to original text color

            this.style.textDecoration = "none"; //reverts to original text state

        }


        gamePiece[i].onclick = function () //activates when mouse clicks on a puzzle piece
        {
            if (checkMove(parseInt(this.innerHTML))) //checks whether or not the puzzle piece can move into an empty space

            {
                swap(this.innerHTML - 1); //moves into an empty space if true


                if (finish()) //checks when the all the 15 pieces are in its right space

                {

                    win(); //alerts the player that they have won the game

                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


spaceX = '300px';
spaceY = '300px';



function checkMove(position) // returns true whenever a piece can be moved into an empty space

{

    if (left(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {
        
        return true;
        totalMoves++;
        

    }



    if (down(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {

        return true;
        totalMoves++;
        
        

    }



    if (up(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {

        return true;
        totalMoves++;
        
        

    }



    if (right(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {

        return true;
        totalMoves++;
        
        

    }
    
}


function Notify() //notifies the user 

{

    notify--; //decrements the value of 

    if (notify == 0) //if the value reaches the end then

    {

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); //retrieves body element in html

        body[0].style.backgroundImage = "none"; //reverts to original page background

        alert('Winner! ... Shuffle and Play Again'); //tells the user that they have won the game 

        para[0].style.visibility = "visible"; //reverts visiblity to its original state

        return;

    } else(notify % 2)

    {

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    }

    timer = setTimeout(Notify, 100); //notifies the user for 1 secs
}

function win() //notifies user that they have won

{

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');




    notify = 10; //initializes notify variable

    timer = setTimeout(Notify, 10);

    para[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; //hides text when user is being notified

}

function finish() //checks when the game reaches its end

{

    var flag = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) //for each puzzle piece 
    {

        var top = parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top);

        var left = parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left);


        if (left != (i % 4 * 100) || top != parseInt(i / 4) * 100) //checks if each piece matches its left and top position

        {

            flag = false;

            break;

        }

    }

    return flag;

}



function left(x, y) //calculates how far to the left a puzzlepiece should position

{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);



    if (cordX > 0)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) + 100 == cordX && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) == cordY)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function right(x, y) //calculates how far to the right a puzzlepiece should position
{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordX < 300)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) - 100 == cordX && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) == cordY)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function up(x, y) //calculates how far up a puzzlepiece should position
{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordY > 0)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) + 100 == cordY && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) == cordX)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function down(x, y) //calculates how far down a puzzlepiece should position

{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordY < 300)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) - 100 == cordY && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) == cordX)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function swap(position) //moves the puzzle piece by switching position with an empty space
{

    var temp = gamePiece[position].style.top;

    gamePiece[position].style.top = spaceY;

    spaceY = temp;

    temp = gamePiece[position].style.left;

    gamePiece[position].style.left = spaceX;

    spaceX = temp;

}

function start()
{
    totalMoves = 0;
    ticker = document.getElementById("Moves");
}

function display()
{
    ticker.innerHTML = totalMoves;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#controls,
#overall,
#puzzlearea {
    width: 400px;
}

#controls {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Used to center the puzzle. */
#overall {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* The area that holds the 15 puzzle pieces. */
#puzzlearea {
    font-size: 32px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

/* This class should be applied to each of the 15 puzzle pieces. */
.puzzlepiece {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 96px;
}

/* This class should be applied to a puzzle piece that can be moved. */
.movablepiece:hover {
    border-color: red;
    color: #006600;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title> 15 Slider Puzzle</title>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="15 Slider.css" />
        <script src="15 Slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
    <body onload = "initialize()">
      <h1>Slider Puzzle</h1>
      <div id="overall">
        <div id="puzzlearea">
          <!-- the following are the fifteen puzzle pieces -->
          <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
          <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
        </div>
        <div id="controls"></div>
        <button onclick = "start();">Start</button>
      <button onclick = "reset();">Reset</button>
      <br>
    Number Of Moves: <span id="Moves">0</span>
      </div><!--content-->
      <br>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define **var totalMoves**  at the beginning in GLOBAL scope.
after **return no code execute so remove totalMoves++;** after return statement
and for display total call you **display();** function in **gamePiece[i].onclick **

```js
var gamePiece;
var notify;
var timer;
var spaceY;
var spaceX;
var ticker;
var totalMoves;

function initialize() {
    var puzzleArea = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
    gamePiece = puzzleArea.getElementsByTagName("div"); //retrieve element within puzzlearea

    for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) //applies features to each puzzle piece 

    {

        gamePiece[i].className = 'puzzlepiece'; //setting up the puzzle piece code

        gamePiece[i].style.left = (i % 4 * 100) + 'px'; //calculates the position for puzzle pieces from the left of the screen

        gamePiece[i].style.top = (parseInt(i / 4) * 100) + 'px'; //calculates the position for puzzle pieces from the top of the screen






        gamePiece[i].onmouseover = function () //applies features when mouse moves over puzzle pieces

        {
            if (checkMove(parseInt(this.innerHTML))) //checks whenever a move is made

            {

                this.style.border = "3px solid red"; //changes to red when a puzzle piece is near an empty space

                this.style.color = "#006600"; //text color changes to green when a puzzle piece is near an empty space

                this.style.textDecoration = "underline"; //underlines the number of the puzzle piece piece
            //console.log(totalMoves);
               

            }
        }


        gamePiece[i].onmouseout = function () //activates whenever mouse moves out of puzzle piece

        {

            this.style.border = "2px solid black"; //reverts to its original size border 

            this.style.color = "#000000"; //reverts to original text color

            this.style.textDecoration = "none"; //reverts to original text state

        }


        gamePiece[i].onclick = function () //activates when mouse clicks on a puzzle piece
        {
            if (checkMove(parseInt(this.innerHTML))) //checks whether or not the puzzle piece can move into an empty space

            {
                swap(this.innerHTML - 1); //moves into an empty space if true
                totalMoves++;
                                 display();

                if (finish()) //checks when the all the 15 pieces are in its right space

                {

                    win(); //alerts the player that they have won the game

                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


spaceX = '300px';
spaceY = '300px';



function checkMove(position) // returns true whenever a piece can be moved into an empty space

{

    if (left(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {
    
             // totalMoves++;   
        return true;
           
        

    }



    if (down(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {
                // totalMoves++;
        return true;
       
        
        

    }



    if (up(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {
                 //totalMoves++;
        return true;
       
        
        

    }



    if (right(spaceX, spaceY) == (position - 1))

    {
                //totalMoves++;
        return true;
        
        
        

    }
    
}


function Notify() //notifies the user 

{

    notify--; //decrements the value of 

    if (notify == 0) //if the value reaches the end then

    {

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); //retrieves body element in html

        body[0].style.backgroundImage = "none"; //reverts to original page background

        alert('Winner! ... Shuffle and Play Again'); //tells the user that they have won the game 

        para[0].style.visibility = "visible"; //reverts visiblity to its original state

        return;

    } else(notify % 2)

    {

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    }

    timer = setTimeout(Notify, 100); //notifies the user for 1 secs
}

function win() //notifies user that they have won

{

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');




    notify = 10; //initializes notify variable

    timer = setTimeout(Notify, 10);

    para[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; //hides text when user is being notified

}

function finish() //checks when the game reaches its end

{

    var flag = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) //for each puzzle piece 
    {

        var top = parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top);

        var left = parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left);


        if (left != (i % 4 * 100) || top != parseInt(i / 4) * 100) //checks if each piece matches its left and top position

        {

            flag = false;

            break;

        }

    }

    return flag;

}



function left(x, y) //calculates how far to the left a puzzlepiece should position

{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);



    if (cordX > 0)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) + 100 == cordX && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) == cordY)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function right(x, y) //calculates how far to the right a puzzlepiece should position
{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordX < 300)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++) {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) - 100 == cordX && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) == cordY)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function up(x, y) //calculates how far up a puzzlepiece should position
{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordY > 0)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) + 100 == cordY && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) == cordX)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function down(x, y) //calculates how far down a puzzlepiece should position

{

    var cordX = parseInt(x);

    var cordY = parseInt(y);

    if (cordY < 300)

    {

        for (var i = 0; i < gamePiece.length; i++)

        {

            if (parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.top) - 100 == cordY && parseInt(gamePiece[i].style.left) == cordX)

            {

                return i;

            }

        }

    } else

    {

        return -1;

    }

}



function swap(position) //moves the puzzle piece by switching position with an empty space
{

    var temp = gamePiece[position].style.top;

    gamePiece[position].style.top = spaceY;

    spaceY = temp;

    temp = gamePiece[position].style.left;

    gamePiece[position].style.left = spaceX;

    spaceX = temp;

}

function start()
{
    totalMoves = 0;
    ticker = document.getElementById("Moves");
}

function display()
{
    ticker.innerHTML = totalMoves;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#controls,
#overall,
#puzzlearea {
    width: 400px;
}

#controls {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Used to center the puzzle. */
#overall {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* The area that holds the 15 puzzle pieces. */
#puzzlearea {
    font-size: 32px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

/* This class should be applied to each of the 15 puzzle pieces. */
.puzzlepiece {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 96px;
}

/* This class should be applied to a puzzle piece that can be moved. */
.movablepiece:hover {
    border-color: red;
    color: #006600;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title> 15 Slider Puzzle</title>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="15 Slider.css" />
        <script src="15 Slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
    <body onload = "initialize()">
      <h1>Slider Puzzle</h1>
      <div id="overall">
        <div id="puzzlearea">
          <!-- the following are the fifteen puzzle pieces -->
          <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
          <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
          <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
        </div>
        <div id="controls"></div>
        <button onclick = "start();">Start</button>
      <button onclick = "reset();">Reset</button>
      <br>
    Number Of Moves: <span id="Moves">0</span>
      </div><!--content-->
      <br>
      </body>
      </head>
</html>
```